# confused with the definition of factory methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory-method

The GoF definition defines the Factory Method pattern as "lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses". I get the idea, but I also pattern as below:

```
public class Point
{
    private double x, y;

    protected Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public static Point NewCartesianPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
    public static Point NewPolarPoint(double rho, double theta)
    {
        return new Point(rho * Math.Cos(theta), rho * Math.Sin(theta));
    }
}
```

I know the benefits to use this pattern, but author said `NewCartesianPoint` and `NewPolarPoint` are also factory methods.

I'm a little bit confused here, below is my questions:

Q1-there is no even a subclass that derived from `Point` here, how come they are factory methods?

Q2-If there are also factory methods, then what's the factory here? the `Point` class?

Comment: A simplistic response would be "it's a factory method as you're not calling a constructor"

Comment: These are [static factory methods](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info).

Answer (score 0):

This is a convenient way of creating two different types of `Point` with static methods, giving [those methods] meaningful names helps the code be self-documenting. They both construct instances of `Point` so you could *loosely* refer to them as "factory methods".

But they are ***not*** the GoF "Factory Method" pattern, which is defined as:

> Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. The Factory method lets a class defer instantiation it uses to subclasses.

The point of using the factory method pattern would be to allow you code such as

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    protected List<IPointFactory> points = new List<IPointFactory>();

    public IEnumerable<Point> GetPoints() => points.Select(p => p.CreatePoint()); 

}

public class Square : Shape
{
    public Square()
    {
        points.Add(new CartesianFactory(0.0,0.0));
        points.Add(new CartesianFactory(1.0,0.0));
        points.Add(new CartesianFactory(0.0,1.0));
        points.Add(new CartesianFactory(1.0,1.0));
    }
}
```

Where you could mix-and-match the `CartesianFactory` with `PolarFactory` as the instantiation of the *actual* `Point` is deferred to the derived type of `IPointFactory`.

This would be equally valid:

```
public class SomeShape : Shape
{
    points.Add(new CartesianFactory(0.0,0.0));
    points.Add(new PolarFactory(10,10));
    points.Add(new CartesianFactory(0.0,1.0));
}
```

You can see the full code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DhdykW

Comment: so what's the official name of this pattern? isn't that too confusing to have it the same name as GoF "Factory Method" pattern but it actually it is not?

Comment: @secondimage there is no official name for this pattern. Two names I have heard/used are "helper methods" or "constructor methods". BTW see update to answer if you're interested what factory methods for your points would actually look like.

Comment: _Static Factory Method_ is the name that has been popularized in Java.